# php mail function won't work in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I use joomla, and specifically I use the extension sourcerer to add code onto existing articles.

I'm making a questionaire, which sends results back to the user via email.

Problem is, the php mail function isn't working and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) && isset($_POST['q1']) && isset($_POST['q2']) && isset($_POST['q3'])) {

$contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
$contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
}
if(!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_email)) {
if (strlen($contact_name)<35 && strlen($contact_email)<50) {

echo $contact_name;
echo '<br>';
echo $contact_email;
echo '<br>';

$q1 = $_POST['q1'];
if ($q1 == 1) {$q1a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
if ($q1 == 2) {$q1a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
if ($q1 == 3) {$q1a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
echo $q1a;
echo '<br>';

$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
if ($q2 == 1) {$q2a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
if ($q2 == 2) {$q2a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
if ($q2 == 3) {$q2a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
echo $q2a;
echo '<br>';

$q3 = $_POST['q3'];
if ($q3 == 1) {$q3a = "Blank Answer A";} ;
if ($q3 == 2) {$q3a = "Blank Answer B";} ;
if ($q3 == 3) {$q3a = "Blank Answer C";} ;
echo $q3a;
echo '<br>';

$to = $contact_email;
$subject = 'Your questionnaire results';
$message = 'This is a test email'."\n\n".'Hope you got it.';
$headers = 'From: email@email.com';

            if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))  {
                echo 'Your results have been sent by email.';

exit();               

                } else {
                    echo 'There was an error sending your results.';
                }

}
else {
echo 'Error: Max length of name or e-mail field exceeded.';
}
} else {
echo "Error: Missing Fields";
}
}

?>


<form name="frm1" action="8-beginners" method="POST">

Name:<br> <input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name" maxlength="34" ><br><br>
E-Mail Address:<br> <input type="text" name="contact_email" id="contact_email" maxlength="49" ><br><br>
question 1:<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" /> Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" /> Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" /> Answer 3<br><br>
question 2:<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" /> Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" /> Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" /> Answer 3<br><br>
question 3:<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" /> Answer 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" /> Answer 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" /> Answer 3<br> <br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your code on localhost or on server? If on localhost - have you got local smtp started?

I will start with remove @ from mail function and see if some error occured.

Comment: I get this error Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\Website\TLSS_SAEA\pascal\plugins\system\sourcerer\helper.php(564) : runtime-created function on line 49 There was an error sending your results.
Name:

Comment: Sure, you haven't got local smtp server. Install Test mail server tool if you have windows http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/ Then edit your php.ini and set smtp values to SMTP = 127.0.0.1 and smtp_port = 25, restart apache and done :)

Comment: A local smtp server... on website that has joomla and already has smtp settings?

Comment: So your code is not on localhost, but on the server. It's the same problem that I described, but provider can block smtp to manual sending mails. Try to contact server administrator.

Comment: I'll do that. Hopefully it'll solve the issue.

Thank you for your time, stranger